# What does 'An Access Violation (Segmentation Fault) raised in your program' mean?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, matrix, int

My C program compiles and works fine until I call this function from main()

```
void rearrangeMainDiagonal(int mat[MAX_ORDER][MAX_ORDER], int order)
{
    int i, j, k=0, l=0, n=0;
    int temp[20], odd_temp[20], even_temp[20];

    for(i=0;i<order;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            temp[k] = mat[i][i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {
        if(temp[i]%2==0)
        {
            even_temp[l] = temp[i];
            l++;
        }
        else
        {
            odd_temp[n] = temp[i];
            n++;
        }
    }

    for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
    {
        temp[j] = odd_temp[j];
    }

    for(i=0;i<=l;i++,j++)
    {
        temp[j] = even_temp[i];
    }

    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            mat[i][i] = temp[k] ;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, a message pops up that says'The program has stopped working. Please close the program. When I try to execute it step by step, it shows 'An Access Violation raised in your program' and stops. Error pops up for the 'for loop' containing line 'temp[j] = odd_temp[j];'.

Comment: Good God that was harsh. Ah... much better.

Comment: A segmentation fault usually means that you either are trying to access an array index which is outside of the array or that you are trying to access a NULL pointer or uninitialized data.

Comment: Run it in a **debugger** like gdb. There is nothing in this code but a crap-ton of array indexing, so you can be all-but assured one of them is overrunning its bounds. *Run it in a debugger*.

Comment: Yes, I can read it, because the site on which I have to submit the code does support much indentation. However I will edit and indent it for you. @jrok

Comment: Most likely `for(i=0;i<=k;i++)` should be `for(i=0;i<k;i++)`

Comment: @WhozCraig The function runs fine when executed separately as a main() function with inputs given. I crashes only when used a function under main().

Comment: @George I tried correcting it, but still the error persists.

Comment: Did you call this function with parameter `order` greater than 19 in your main() ?

Comment: @Philipp I checked them. There is no such mistake.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<order;i++){ for(j=0;j<order;j++){  temp[k] = mat[i][i];    k++; }}`. either `mat[i][j]` or the second loop is not necessary.

Comment: Same problem here `for(j=0;j<=n;j++)` and here `for(i=0;i<=l;i++,j++)`. Replace <= with <.

Comment: Too much information -> try either debugging it manually or adding "print"s of i, j and k within the "for"s.

Comment: *"The function runs fine when executed separately as a main() function..."* I seriously doubt that. It may *appear* to "run fine" but the problems in this code are going to exhibit undefined behavior. "fine" is the "lucky" side of that behavior in this case. *Run it in a debugger*.

Answer (score 2):

A Segmentation Fault happens when your program tries to access memory that was not allocated to that program.

The most common reason for a Segmentation Fault (except dereferencing a NULL pointer) is to access an array beyond its bounds.

f.ex:

```
int arr[5];
for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
    arr[i]=i;
```

will throw an Segmentation fault because you access the 5th element of `arr` which does not exist (and thus you try to access the memory behind it which was not allocated to you.

There are multiple places in your program where this can happen.

```
void rearrangeMainDiagonal(int mat[MAX_ORDER][MAX_ORDER], int order)
{
    int i, j, k=0, l=0, n=0;
```

you create fixed sized arrays but you never check your index when you use them.
if all my other adjustments are correct it is better to use:

```
    int temp[MAX_ORDER], odd_temp[MAX_ORDER], even_temp[MAX_ORDER];
```

and enforce order to be lower or equal to MAX_ORDER:

```
    assert(order <= MAX_ORDER);
```

based on the function name I suspect that this

```
    for(i=0;i<order;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            temp[k] = mat[i][i];
            k++;
        }
    }
```

which requires `temp` to be `order*order` in size;

should be more like

```
    for(i=0;i<order;i++) 
    {
        temp[i] = mat[i][i];
    }
```

thus placing every element on the main diagonal once in the `temp` array which now should only be `order` in size

here you loop over temp until the `k`'th element, which you did not set in your version of the above loop since you did increment k after the assignment
so you should loop until `k-1` so use `i<k` instead of `i<=k`;

```
    for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
```

should become (after the change in the loop above);

```
    for(i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        if(temp[i]%2==0)
        {
            even_temp[l] = temp[i];
            l++;
        }
        else
        {
            odd_temp[n] = temp[i];
            n++;
        }
    }
```

again the `n`'th element of `odd_temp` is not set, use `j<n`

```
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        temp[j] = odd_temp[j];
    }
```

again the `l`'th element of `even_temp` is not set, use `i<l`

```
    for(i=0;i<l;i++,j++)
    {
        temp[j] = even_temp[i];
    }
```

here the same mistake as in the first loop happens.
this should become:

```
    for(i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        mat[i][i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

now you can also remove the variable k since it is unused, and if the function does still do what you wanted it to do, it should be able to handle matrices with order up to `MAX_ORDER`